# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, Alguém me ajuda!

Tags: python

não consigo identificar o erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém poderia me dizer onde está!

Comment: falta os dois pontos na declaração da função.

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definindo uma Função:**

Você pode definir funções para fornecer a funcionalidade necessária,
aqui estão regras simples para definir uma função no Python.

- Blocos de função começam com a palavra-chave def seguida pelo nome da
  função e parênteses (()).
- Quaisquer parâmetros ou argumentos de entrada devem ser colocados
  dentro desses parênteses. Você também pode definir parâmetros dentro
  desses parênteses.
- A primeira instrução de uma função pode ser uma instrução opcional -
  a cadeia de documentação da função ou docstring.
- O bloco de código dentro de **cada função começa com dois pontos (:)** e
  é recuado.
- A instrução return [expressão] sai de uma função, retornando
  opcionalmente uma expressão ao chamador. Uma instrução de retorno sem
  argumentos é a mesma que retornar Nenhuma.

Exemplo da sintaxe correta:

```
def minhaFunção( params ):
```

[Veja mais sobre isto aqui.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Tem que colocar dois pontos quando for declarar função, assim:

```
def derivadas(temps, A):
```